# Getting Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: angular, api, spring-boot, jpa, angular8

I'm trying to acces API on localhost 8080 called eatGroups:

I'm getting this error in a Angular8 frontend:

### component.html file looks like

```
   <li *ngFor="let eatGroup of eatgroupService">
        {{ eatGroup.name }}
   </li>
```

### component.ts looks like:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EatgroupService} from "../eatgroup.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-eatgroup-list',
  templateUrl: './eatgroup-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./eatgroup-list.component.css']
})
export class EatgroupListComponent implements OnInit {
  eatgroups: Array<any>;

  constructor(private eatgroupService: EatgroupService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.eatgroupService.getAll().subscribe(data => {
      this.eatgroups = data;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

### eatgroup.service.ts look like:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable} from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class EatgroupService {


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  public getAll(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('//localhost:8080/eatGroups');
  }

}
```

### Browser

But when i go to my browser, i get a message in the console:
Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try this: `<li *ngFor="let eatGroup of eatgroups">`

Comment: Tried it, i get the same error.

Comment: could you log what the value of data looks like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using an `*ngFor` on `eatgroupService` which is essentially an Object. I think you wanted to iterate through `eatgroups` which is your array.

This:

```
<li *ngFor="let eatGroup of eatgroupService">
    {{ eatGroup.name }}
</li>
```

Should be:

```
<li *ngFor="let eatGroup of eatgroups">
    {{ eatGroup.name }}
</li>
```

You might also want to initialize them to an empty array:

```
eatgroups: Array<any> = [];
```

#### BETTER APPROACH

Don't `subscribe` to the `Observable`. Use the `async` pipe in the template instead:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';
import { EatgroupService} from "../eatgroup.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-eatgroup-list',
  templateUrl: './eatgroup-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./eatgroup-list.component.css']
})
export class EatgroupListComponent implements OnInit {
  eatGroups$: Observable<Array<any>>;

  constructor(private eatgroupService: EatgroupService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.eatGroups$ = this.eatgroupService.getAll();
  }
}
```

And then in your template:

```
<ul *ngIf="eatGroups$ | async as eatGroups">
  <li *ngFor="let eatGroup of eatGroups">
    {{ eatGroup.name }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

**PS:** Make sure that you are indeed getting an array from the `getAll()` method.